# Should a Builder be created by a Factory?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Complex objects are often created by the Builder pattern, where a Builder is an object dedicated to the creation of a single object through multiple methods. E.G. (pseudocode):

```
class PersonBuilder
    PersonBuilder Named(string name)
        this.name = name
        return this

    PersonBuilder Aged(int age)
        this.age = age
        return this

    Person GetPerson()
        return new Person(this.name, this.age)
```

This stateful structure with a fluent interface is common in the builder pattern:

```
myPerson = builder.Named("John").Aged(20).GetPerson();
```

Therefore, **is it wise to create a `PersonBuilderFactory` from which you can create the builder?** Or should you just take a dependency on a `PersonBuilder` and assume that your class will be injected with a new object? The latter approach means that when you have created your `Person` you should probably reset the builder. What is best practice here, and why?

Comment: Make your builders immutable, and there is no need to "reset" them.

Comment: @BenJames this is probably the best answer I've seen..! If you could write it as an answer (and perhaps give an example of how to do this) I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As the commentor to my question has not opted to respond with an answer I will provide one that I think is acceptable)

Making your Builder immutable is answer to this problem. You can take advantage of the fact that an instance will have access to the private members of another instance. The original example thus becomes:

```
class PersonBuilder
    PersonBuilder(PersonBuilder copy) // copy constructor
        this.name = copy.name
        this.age = copy.age

    PersonBuilder Named(string name)
        newBuilder = new PersonBuilder(this)
        newBuilder.name = name
        return newBuilder

    PersonBuilder Aged(int age)
        newBuilder = new PersonBuilder(this)
        newBuilder.age = age
        return newBuilder

    Person GetPerson()
        return new Person(this.name, this.age)
```

This way, it is still possible to use the builder like so:

```
myPerson = builder.Named("John").Aged(20).GetPerson();
```

However, the original builder object will remain unchanged, and can be used repeatedly.

Thanks to Ben James for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, I like the following pattern (which requires lambda functions):

```
var person = PersonBuilder.Create(p => p.Named("John").Aged(20));
```

Where it's implemented something like this:

```
class PersonBuilder
{
    private PersonBuilder() { /* ... */ }

    public static Person Create(Action<PersonBuilder> configure)
    {
        var builder = new PersonBuilder();
        configure(builder);
        return builder.Build();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is nice syntax but introduces a concrete dependency of PersonBuilder. I never use static factory methods for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

In original [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) there is a Director.
As I understand, the director incapsulates the work with builder.
If you need to reset the builder somehow(for example, call dispose for TcpClient inside builder), do that in director.

How  and where to instantiate a concrete builder?
If, for example, you have 3 document formats(TXT, PDF, Excel) and user can select among of them, you will need factory in this case

```
class BuilderFactory
{
  public IBuilder Create(DocumentType type)
  {
    if(type == DocumentType.TXT)
      return new TxtBuilder();

    if(type == DocumentType.Pdf)
      return new PdfBuilder();

    //...
  }
}
```

If during application execution time builder is the same, you can put the concrete builder in config(espesially if you use DI).
If you know the concrete builder at design time you can just use new operator.

Comment: If you use the `new` operator then you are violating the dependency inversion principle. You should never "know" the concrete builder type - *program to a contract*

Comment: The director should not know the concrete builder, but it is possible for the code that uses the director to use new operator. It defentely violates dependency inversion principle, but it is fine for me in some cases. Cosider you dont use dependency injection in your project and you strictly folow D principle - u will have IDirector, IBuilder, and one or few interfaces for factories, implementations for them and i guess singleton that holds concrete instanses for factories...uh that all instead of just IBuilder, Director and ConcreteBuilder

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on your builder class...I prefer create a `XXXBuilderFactory` when I have to apply some logic in the `Builder` creation, otherwise, I think, just the builder is enough in this way the code remains simpler.

Answer (score -1):

Generally builder should be immutable there should be no concept of reset in it.but still that depends on your need on what u need to achieve ....